# Adding Unique ID to table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add a unique ID to an existing table that has data inserted into it.  I don't need a new value with each row, rather, with each instance of an insert.  The time stamp indicates a new insert.  Can anyone be kind enough point me in the right direction?  My current table is basically column a and the time stamp.

```
ID     COLUMN A    TIME STAMP
1        abc       05-09-2013 11:00:23
1        bcd       05-09-2013 11:00:23
1        ab3       05-09-2013 11:00:23
2        abc       05-09-2013 11:15:00
2        123       05-09-2013 11:15:00
3        abc       05-09-2013 11:18:07
4        abc       05-09-2013 11:19:55
4        123       05-09-2013 11:19:55
4        165       05-09-2013 11:19:55
4        def       05-09-2013 11:19:55
```

Comment: Your example ID is not unique. You could just use the table as is and stick an index on the time stamp column, since that's the value you're interested in. Hardly a proper solution, but... It would also help to tell us why you want to add this new ID and what its use case is.

Comment: the values will be inserted into the table, but another column in the table will be updated with comments.  the unique id will serve as a reference to update (UPDATE Table SET Comments = 'comments for this ID' where ID = 1).  Using a GUID is discouraged as it's too many characters to remember/reference.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of any easy way to put unique id based on each insert instance. One idea can be to use trigger on the table where you can inspect how the data getting inserted and add ID value before data gets inserted into table.

Answer (score 0):

First create a ID column which allows null.
Then write a procedure which has a cursor on a query which does a order by and group by on time stamp column.
For every row increase a count by one
update table with id = counter whwre times tamp = time stamp in query

At end of this add constraint on id column to make it not null

Answer (score 0):

You are going to likely want an auto-increment field.  Use IDENTITY for this in SQL Server.  This will enable you to insert without supplying this p_id value and the value will be auto incremented.

You don't want to use timestamps for uniqueness because it is difficult and costly to index.  It is also difficult to ensure uniqueness among time values.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your insert is not very frequent. You can use time stamp to get unique Id.
e.g. 130509110023

You can do some math to get appropriate function as required data length, which will give you unique id